# How can I make this abstract wavy shape?

Tags: modeling

[image]

Anyone know how to make this shape? Don't answer with displace > clouds or something like that. I want the entire plane to become deformed like this.

Comment: What do you mean by "this shape"? Exactly the one we see or a somehow wavy shape like this: [wavy plane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzb5a.jpg)? If not the exact shape but only something like the image, then I'm afraid I cannot answer your question because you don't want "displace > clouds" as an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a plane, subdivide, lift up some of its edes with the *Proportional Editing* option on, duplicate, give it a *Solidify* modifier:

[image]

Give it a material rather glossy, with a bit of *Subsurface* and a *Noise Texture* to give it a bit of grain:

[image]

Comment: That worked really well thank you!

Comment: @JoshAppel -- don't forget to check the "Accept Answer" button as moonboots put some effort into this answer and he deserved to get to 1m points by tomorrow, LOL.

Comment: Why do "the kids" not "accept answer" anymore?!  Like your time is not valuable !

Comment: I'm not sure everyone understands how BSE works at the beginning   ;)